# ER_BUS_SET_WRONG_SIGNATURE - Android and Windows interaction through Alljoyn

Tags: java, android, windows-10-universal, alljoyn

As a part of my project i am trying to interact with and Android App and a Windows UWP App using the Alljoyn protocol which uses the DBUS Specification.

I am using the LSF interface and trying to set the Hue, Saturation, Brightness and Color Temperature Values. As per the interface these values are uint(unsigned int 32bit) and hence their Signature is ("u").
But in Android there is no possibility of Uint and hence I am using int type and hence the Signature in java is ("i"). When i try to set the values for Hue, Saturation and others i get the following error

ER_BUS_SET_WRONG_SIGNATURE

How can I overcome this problem?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks and regards
Ajit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah found the solution..!

there was a mistake in my java interface..!

*@BusProperty(signature = "u")*

solved the problem...!

Thanks and hope this helps the others too.. :)

Comment: you might accept your own answer to close the question